# How to use item renderer to view multiple fields?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

Our app contacts the server, and get a json based array, each item has:

```
First_Name 
Last_Name
Image_Url
```

So, how to use the item renderer so that we can use custom data template to view name and image?

Also, can we have access to the json item being rendered from inside the renderer code?
Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d3836ecbb5ec129ec77b1e1-8000.html

just above the 'Controlling the background display of an item renderer' section, there is a custom itemrenderer example, you can use it.

Comment: They used "MySimpleItemRendererFunction" for custom render, but the "MySimpleItemRendererFunction" is not there .. !

Comment: You have to see above the  'Controlling the background display of an item renderer' section.

Answer (score 0):

Find below link to add custom item renderer

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex4_03.html